# spring cloud stream and zookeeper

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-stream

I've two applications :

- the first one produce messages in kafka
- the second one receives all these messages

I've configured 
`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers` and `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.defaultBrokerPort`.
Everything works well.

In the documentation I see 
`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes` and `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.defaultZkPort`
to define a list of ZooKeeper nodes to which the Kafka binder can connect.

In my understanding, i just have to connect my application to kafka.
So could you explain me when it's usable, or could you give me a use case where i have to define the zookeeper relative properties.

Answer (score 3):

Zookeeper is used for allowing the Kafka binder to create topics automatically (using binder options, such as the partition count, or number of concurrent instances - as opposed to relying on the broker to create them). If you don't need the feature, you can disable topic auto-creation. 
See the discussion here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/37.

This is a feature available since 1.1. In 1.0 Zookeeper was needed by the 0.8 SimpleConsumer client.